# Extreme cases when counting functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Suppose $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{c\}$. There's one function between $A$ and $B$. Actually counting the number of injective, surjective and most other functions is not difficult. I am confused by extreme cases.

Suppose $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \{q, w, e, r, t, y\}$. Then there's precisely one map from $A $ to $B$. But there's no map from $B$ to $A$. Also there's one map between two empty sets. How do they determine the number of functions in these extreme cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$, then the number of functions $f: A \to B$ is $n^m$ since there are $n$ possible images for each of the $m$ elements in the domain.

In your example, $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{c\}$, the number of functions $f: A \to B$ is $1^2 = 1$ since there is one possible image for each of the two elements in the domain.

In your example, $A = \emptyset$ and $B = \{q, w, e, r, t, y\}$, the number of functions $f: A \to B$ is $6^0 = 1$ (the empty function), and the number of functions $g: B \to A$ is $0^6 = 0$ since there are no elements in the codomain with which to associate an element in the domain.

The formula is consistent with the convention that the empty product $0^0 = 1$ since there one map from the empty set to itself (the empty function).

Comment: Oh, this is great. I was thinking about it like this: if $A = \{a, b\}$ and $B = \{c, d\}$, then in how many ways can we replace $x \in (a, x), (b, x)?$ From here, I couldn't quite see how to construct a pair from sets when at least one is empty. It never occurred to me to use the formula. Thanks. Apologies for my English.